# how to repeat or reset a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 5 thumbnails lined up together and 2 arrows that slide them up and down. 
Right now, you can click up twice and down twice-- and that's it, nothing moves. My goal is to be able to go back and click up and down multiple times.

http://jsfiddle.net/acfS6/

```
$('#tmbDown').css ('opacity', '.6');

var timesClickedUp = 0;     

$('#tmbUp').bind('click', function (event) {

  $("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "-=100px"}, "slow");
  timesClickedUp++;

  if (timesClickedUp >= 2) {
    $(this).unbind(event);
    $('#tmbDown').css ('opacity', '1');
    $('#tmbUp').css ('opacity', '.6');    

  }

});


var timesClickedDown = 0;

$('#tmbDown').bind('click', function (event) {

  $("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "+=100px"}, "slow")
  timesClickedDown++;

  if (timesClickedDown >= 2) {
    $(this).unbind(event);    
    $('#tmbDown').css ('opacity', '.6');
    $('#tmbUp').css ('opacity', '1');
  }



});
​
```

Comment: why are you unbinding the event after 2 clicks?  that will stop you from processing clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest thing you may have missed is that when you click on the down arrow, you need to decrement your timesClickedUp and vice versa.

Then you need to fade/show both arrows based on the value of their corresponding "timesClicked" values.

Here's how I did it:

http://jsfiddle.net/acfS6/2/

```
var timesClickedUp = 0,
    timesClickedDown = 2;

function updateOpacities() {
    var $tmbUp = $('#tmbUp'),
        $tmbDown = $('#tmbDown');

    timesClickedUp >= 2 ? $tmbUp.css('opacity', '.6') : $tmbUp.css('opacity', '1');
    timesClickedDown >= 2 ? $tmbDown.css('opacity', '.6') : $tmbDown.css('opacity', '1');
}

// Call updateOpacities to initialize the arrows.
updateOpacities();

$('#tmbUp').bind('click', function(event) {

    if (timesClickedUp < 2) {
        $("#tmbHolder").animate({
            "marginTop": "-=100px"
        }, "slow");
        timesClickedUp++;
        timesClickedDown--;
    }

    updateOpacities();
});



$('#tmbDown').bind('click', function(event) {

    if (timesClickedDown < 2) {
        $("#tmbHolder").animate({
            "marginTop": "+=100px"
        }, "slow")
        timesClickedDown++;
        timesClickedUp--;
    }
    updateOpacities();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this. A small variation : http://jsfiddle.net/wghk8/

```
var timesClickedUp = 0;


$('#tmbUp').bind('click', function(event) {

if (timesClickedUp < 2) {
    $("#tmbHolder").animate({
        "marginTop": "-=100px"
    }, "slow");
    timesClickedUp++;
}
else {

    $("#tmbHolder").animate({
        "marginTop": "+=" + (timesClickedUp * 100) + "px"
    }, "slow");
    timesClickedUp = 0;
}
});
var timesClickedDown = 0;

$('#tmbDown').bind('click', function(event) {
if (timesClickedDown < 2) {
    $("#tmbHolder").animate({
        "marginTop": "+=100px"
    }, "slow")
    timesClickedDown++;
}
else {
    $("#tmbHolder").animate({
        "marginTop": "-=" + (timesClickedDown * 100) + "px"
    }, "slow");
    timesClickedDown = 0;
}
});​
```